# Best way to match similar words?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to display a list of words that are similar to what the user is typing. For example, if I have a list of words like ["Software Eng 1", "Software Eng 2", "Blah"]

And the user typed S, it would filter to the Software Eng 1 and Software Eng 2. Again, the user types So and it filters to the same two words. But if the user types Soc, it would have nothing. What is the best way to do this? I tried

```
for (EmployeeName r : list)
{
    if (textField.getText().matches(r.getName()))
    {
        System.out.println(r.getName() + " is similar");
    }
    else System.out.println("NOPE");
}
```

But this only seems to be catching the case when textField.getText() is exactly the same

Comment: You need to define *similar* more clearly. What if they type "so"? What about "oft"? What about "En"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you could use [String#startsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) if you're checking whether
   any `Employees` name within the list *starts with* the text entered.

Example:

```
for (EmployeeName r : list)
{
    if (r.getName().startsWith(textField.getText()))
    {
        System.out.println(r.getName() + " is similar");
    } 
}
```

2. if you're looking to see if the text entered is contained *anywhere* within the `Employees` name
   then [String#contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) would do the job.
3. you could even use [String#indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) to check if the text entered is contained *anywhere* within the `Employees` name.

Example:

```
for (EmployeeName r : list)
{
    if (r.getName().indexOf(textField.getText()) != -1)
    {
        System.out.println(r.getName() + " is similar");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains` for example ;

```
textField.getText().toLowerCase().contains(r.getName().toLowerCase())
```